# Let $p,q$ are distinct primes and $G$ be a group of order $pq$ then which of the following is true?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p,q$ are distinct primes and $G$ be a group of order $pq$ then which of the following is true?

$1.G$ has exactly $4$ subgroups upto isomorphism.

$2.G$ is abelian.

$3.G$ is isomorphiq to a subgroup of $S_{pq}$.

My attempt: First option is true.

Second option is false $S_3$ is a counterexample.

My problem:I think third option is correct.Is it correct or not?

Comment: you heard of group actions??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes but not so much just may be definition.

Comment: Nice... That must be enough... You heard regular action??? Supposing $G$ has $ n$ elements we consider $G\times \{g_1,g_2,\cdots , g_n\}\rightarrow \{g_1,g_2,\cdots , g_n\}$ with $(g,g_i)\rightarrow g\cdot g_i =g_j$?? have you seen such action?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sorry but not ok I will check on google you just tell me your answer.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I want to solve

Comment: Good... You check that what i have said is actually an action.... each element in $g$ gives you a permutation.... $g$ takes $g_1$ to $gg_1$ and $g_2$ to $gg_2$ and so on... do you understand this???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik $g,g_1,g_2$ are all from $G$ and what is the permutation?$g$ is the permutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ has $n$ elements $\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\}$...

Consider the action $\eta : G\times \{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\}\rightarrow \{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\}$

By this we mean, given $g\in G$  we have $\eta _g : \{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\}\rightarrow \{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\}$ with $g\cdot g_i\mapsto gg_i$

This $\eta_g$ is a permutation...

This $\eta_g$ is a permutation on set of $n$ elements so is an element of $S_n$

So, you have map $\eta: G\rightarrow S_n$  with $g\rightarrow \eta_g$

If you can prove that this is an injective homomorphism then you have $G\leq S_n$

So, any group of order $n$ is a subgroup of symmetric group on $n$ elements...

Can you fill the gaps??

Can you see how this is related to your third question??

Answer (score 5):

[The Cayley's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_theorem) solves your question: *every* finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the permutations group $S_n$.

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Saying every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of **the** permutations group does not mean much unless you say what that  permutation group is...

Comment: Yes I know the cayley's theorem but how we are sure that $G$ is isomorphic to exactly to a SUBGROUP OF $S_{pq}$?

Comment: @Flip Cayley's theorem implies if $G$ has order $n$ it must be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. Apply here with $n=pq$. Are you *sure* you know Cayley's theorem?